# jackknife replicate weights for survey data

Tags: survey, jackknife

I am confused about utilizing the jackknife replicate weights for computing the variance. From the second equation on page 192 of STATA's documentation (http://www.stata.com/manuals13/svy.pdf), the variance must take into consideration fpc and the number of clusters per stratum, ie
$\hat{V}(\hat{\theta}) = \sum_{0}^{L} (1-f_{h})m_{h}\sum_{0}^{n_h} (\hat{\theta}_{(h,i)} - \hat{\theta})(\hat{\theta}_{(h,i)} - \hat{\theta})$ where L is the number of strata, $n_{h}$ is the number of clusters per stratum while $m_{h}$ is $\frac{n_{h} -1 }{n_{h}}$, $(1-f_{h})$ is the fpc, and $\hat{\theta}_{(h,i)}$ is the estimate from leaving out the ith PSU in stratum h. $\hat{\theta}_{(h,i)}$ is for each replicate weight. The replicate weights can either be calculated if you have stratum and PSU information, or they are provided (and stratum and PSU information is not) for privacy reasons.

The issue is that, if the replicate weights are provided with the data, typically fpc and $n_{h}$ are not provided. So $\hat{V}(\hat{\theta})$ must be different when the weights are provided instead of calculated, just from looking at the formula. But my professor says I should get the same results when calculating the jackknife weights vs providing those same jackknife weights.. I'm not sure how this is the case